# I have scheduled a Cron job for once a month at exact time in node js, what if for some reason server would fail in that time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, backend

Is there a way to be sure that crone will work in any case after the server is running again?

```
const cronServiceStatistic = new CronJob(' 0 0 1 * * ', (async () => {
    console.log('cron is working')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cronjob that is run when the server boot. Instead of the format "0 0 1 * *", you can use "@reboot" to run a command every time your server starts.

Comment: For what it's worth the question is about node-cron and not UNIX cron. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: using `@reboot` is not recommended. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly concerned about the possibility that a scheduled cron job will not run at the appointed time due to a network or hardware failure.

Making cron jobs resilient to this kind of failure involves a few things:

1. It must be possible to invoke the cron job code too often (more than once a month in your case) without damaging your system.  This can be done by saving the timestamp of the last successful run in some kind of persistent storage. Then, another run can simply return if you attempt to run it too often.
2. You must invoke the cron job code when your system starts up (after a reboot or a software restart, for example). That way you won't fail to run it even if your system is offline. Item 1 above will ensure the startup run doesn't damage your system.
3. You should have it write log entries describing what it's doing every time it runs. You *will* want to know what happened sometimes.
4. You should avoid the hour between 02:00 and 03:00 local time as the appointed time to run. In most timezones, that hour does not exist on the day of conversion from standard to daylight time. And it exists twice on the day of conversion back to standard time.
5. **Edit** If you can, avoid the exact midnight hour, or the exact top of any hour, as the time to run your job. Why? lots of people don't avoid the midnight hour when configuring this kind of thing. That means a lot of things can happen all at once on a busy application.  If you specify, for example, twelve minutes past the hour your job has a smaller chance of running at exactly the same time as others. Less chance for deadlocks and slowdowns. (Also, if various server clocks are not in sync with each other, it may still look like yesterday on some servers when your job starts precisely at midnight. You DON'T want to explain to your CFO why month-end processing failed because of a problem with the network time protocol.)

Comment: what if I will not set a time, and I will just set the first day of month, when that will run?

Comment: The way cron patterns -- in your case `0 0 1 * *` -- you always specify a time. In your case you have specified the time `00:00` and the first day of each month. This will work. BUT, see my edit.